# How do you default select the file type on NSSavePanel?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

[image]

How do I programmatically default select the file format in NSSavePanel?

I have it currently set to image types only, however it always defaults to TIFF.

```
NSSavePanel *savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
_saveOptions = [[IKSaveOptions alloc] initWithImageProperties: _imageProperties
                                                  imageUTType: _imageUTType];

[_saveOptions addSaveOptionsAccessoryViewToSavePanel: savePanel];
```

Comment: And what values do `_imageProperties` and `_imageUTType` have?

Answer (score 0):

Ken's comment lead me in correct direction. Passing in imageUTType will default the NSSavePanel selection.

```
_saveOptions = [[IKSaveOptions alloc] initWithImageProperties: _imageProperties
                                                  imageUTType:(NSString*)kUTTypeJPEG];
```