# NSDocument-Based Application: Selecting Default File Type in NSSavePanel

Tags: swift, cocoa, info.plist, nsdocument, nssavepanel

[image]

I'm playing with the `NSDocument` class to make a simple document-based application.  My info.plist contains four document content type identifiers including public.text, public.plain-text, public.source-cde, public.rtf as shown above.  And I get those file types listed if I involke the save-panel (`NSSavePanel`) as shown below.

[image]

My question is whether or not it is possible to select one of the file types programmatically.  Can I select 'rich text (RTF)' when the save panel appears?

The following is part of my document (`NSDocument`) file.

```
import Cocoa

class Document: NSDocument {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    override class var autosavesInPlace: Bool {
        return false
    }
    
    override func save(withDelegate delegate: Any?, didSave didSaveSelector: Selector?, contextInfo: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
        if let _ = fileURL {
            Swift.print("Saved!!!")
        } else {
            Swift.print("Not saved yet...")
            NSApp.sendAction(#selector(NSDocument.saveAs(_:)), to: nil, from: self)
        }
    }
    
    override func writableTypes(for saveOperation: NSDocument.SaveOperationType) -> [String] {
        return super.writableTypes(for: saveOperation)
    }
    
    override func prepareSavePanel(_ savePanel: NSSavePanel) -> Bool {
        savePanel.allowsOtherFileTypes = true
        savePanel.isExtensionHidden = false
        
        guard let accessoryView = savePanel.accessoryView else { return true }
        for sub in accessoryView.subviews {
            Swift.print("Class: \(sub.className)")
            /*
            if sub.isKind(of: NSPopUpButton.self) {
                if let popUpButton = sub as? NSPopUpButton {
                    popUpButton.selectItem(at: 5)
                    Swift.print("Sure")
                }
            }
            */
            
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42104560/how-do-you-default-select-the-file-type-on-nssavepanel) as a similar title where he uses `IKSaveOptions`, which is used 'for saving image data' according to the doc.  My application deals with text.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to select the file type of a new document or do you want to change the file type of an existing document?

Comment: @Willeke Thank you for your question.  I just need to select the third one from the file drop-down menu.  But if it makes any difference, I say I want to select a spefic one for a new document.

Comment: Have you tried setting `fileType`?

Comment: @Willeke Setting fileType to what?  I doubt I have done it, anyway.

Comment: @ElTomato have you trying adding the extension to the file name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default file format is `fileType`. Set `fileType` in `writableTypes(for:)` or `runModalSavePanel(for:delegate:didSave:contextInfo:)`.

```
override func writableTypes(for saveOperation: NSDocument.SaveOperationType) -> [String] {
    fileType = "public.rtf"
    return super.writableTypes(for: saveOperation)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Whoa...  Under `writableTypes(for:)`?  Who would figure that out?  If you can tell me, how do you know that?  Is that because you have years of experience with `NSDocument`?

Comment: Yes, years of experience with Cocoa. I looked at the TextEdit sample code and did some debugging.

Comment: I have done that once, i think.  All right.  Thanks again.